# Modular Exponentiation

Tags: exponentiation, cryptography

Give an estimate of the maximum number of arithmetic operations required in a fast
exponentiation when the exponent has 100 decimal digits.

talked to prof about this review question, didn't really understand the reply, it was along the lines of, 
2<sup>100</sup> = 1000 digits = 10<sup>3 x 10</sup>  = 330 binary digits x 2 = 660 operations
, just hoping someone could explain the steps to get to 660 operations

Comment: If we assume that every digit needs to be processed, we have an exponent operation and a modulus operation for each digit.  The process of modular exponentiation works best in binary-based computers using the binary number system, so we would convert the number of decimal digits to the number of binary digits.  Does this help?

Comment: The very first conversion from decimal to binary happens as $2^{10}=1024\approx 10^3$.  So $10^{100}=10\cdot 10^{3\cdot 33}\approx 10\cdot 2^{10\cdot 33}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is probably that a number with $100$ decimal digits will have about $330$ bits -- and using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), you will need either one or two modular multiplications per bit position in the exponent, for a worst-case of about $660$ modular multiplications.

This does not count how much work it is to do *one* modular multiplication (which generally involves one bignum multiplication and a division with remainder, unless you use something like [Montgomery reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication)), nor does it take into account that *squarings* of large numbers can be done somewhat cheaper than general multiplications.

Comment: I've just discovered I mistakenly edited your answer to add  the description of the fast exponentiation algorithm, instead of mine. I deeply apologise for this error.

Comment: @Bernard: I did wonder. Are you planning on moving it back? :)

Comment: No, it's not necessary. But usually, I do not touch upon other answers, so I feel confused.

Comment: @Bernard: I'll do it, then.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm consists in squaring at most $n$ times if the exponent is $2^n$, and multiplying when the quotient of the exponent by $2$ in the procedure is odd. So there are at most $n$ squarings and $n$ multiplication – in all at most $2n$ arithmetic operations.

That said an exponent with $100$ decimal digits is an exponent $\; <10^{100}=\bigl(10^3\bigr)^{\tfrac{100}3}<\bigl(2^{10}\bigr)^{33.4}$ $=2^{334}$. So the algorithm will require at most $668$ arithmetic operations.

*Description of the algorithm in pseudo-code*:

**Input:** exponent N,  number $a$

**Output:** $a^N$.

**Variables:** $x, n, P$.

**Initialisation:** $x\leftarrow a,\;n \leftarrow N, \;P\leftarrow 1$.

WHILE $n>0$ DO

$\qquad$ IF $n$ ODD DO $\;P\leftarrow x*P\;$ ENDIF;

$\qquad\; n\leftarrow \lfloor n/2\rfloor$; $ x\leftarrow x^2$;

ENDWHILE

OUTPUT $P$